# Construction of the completion of a measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\overline{M}$ be collection of $E \cup Z$ such that $E \in M$ and $Z \subset F$, where $F \in M,$ and $\mu(F) = 0.$ We also know $\bar{\mu}(E) = \mu(E).$

a) Show $\overline{M}$ is smallest sigma algebra containing $M$ and all subsets of elements of $M$ that have measure $0$.

Attempt: Notice if $E_{1} \subset \overline{M}$ then $E_{1} = E \cup Z.$ Since $E, Z \in M$ then $E_{1}^c = (E \cup F)^c \cup (F-Z)$ is in $M$ since $(E \cup F),(F-Z) \in M.$ Hence $\overline{M}$ is sigma algebra. If we let $Z = \emptyset$,then we see $M \subset \overline{M}.$ And since $\emptyset \in M,$ then let $E = \emptyset$, and then all subsets of $M$ with measure $0$ is in $M.$ Does this look okay? I am not sure how to show $\overline{M}$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing $M$

b) Show $\bar{\mu}$ is a measure of $\overline{M},$ and this measure is a completion.

Attempt: First check $\bar{\mu}$ is a measure of $\overline{M}.$ Notice $\bar{\mu}(\emptyset) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0.$ If $A_{1} \subset A_{2}$, and $A_{1} = B_{1} \cup C_{1}, A_{2} = B_{2} \cup C_{2},$ then $\bar{\mu}(A_1) = \mu(B_1) \le \mu(B_2) = \bar{\mu}(A_2).$ Lastly $\bar{\mu}(\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}) = {\mu}(\cup_{i=1}^{n}B_{i}) \le \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(B_i).$ Next for completion, we need to show if $F \in \overline{M}$ and $\bar{\mu}(F) = 0,$ if $E\subset F$ then $E \in \overline{M}.$ I am not sure how to this.

Comment: I don't see where you proved closure under countable unions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempt of (a):

What you did here seems okay.  Make sure to realize $E_1 \in \overline{M}$, not $E_1 \subset \overline{M}$.

To show it's the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra, you have to show $$\overline{M} = \bigcap N$$ where the intersection is over all complete $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ that contain $M$.

Your question on (b) follows from monotonicity, or write $E$ as $\emptyset \cup E$.

Comment: I am trying the subset approach to show the equality for part a), but its not working out. Any hints on how to approach showing its the smallest sigma algebra containing M?

Comment: @user77404 To show $\overline{M} \subset \cap N$, it suffices to show that $\overline{M} \subset N$ whenever $N$ is a _complete_ $\sigma$-algebra containing $M$. For the opposite inclusion, just note that $\overline{M}$ is a complete $\sigma$-algebra containing $M$, so $$\bigcap N = \overline{M} \bigcap (\bigcap_{N \neq \overline{M}} N) \subset \overline{M}$$

Comment: @user77404 your first statement is proving it is the smallest, since you claim $\bar{M}⊂N$ for all complete σ-algebra containing $M$. If it is proved, nothing more is needed to prove. But, how we can show that?

Comment: @andybenji can you continue your solution part (b) further?

Answer (score 3):

The argument "since $E, Z \in M$" is incorrect, since **$Z$ needn't be in $M$**. It is true, though, that $Z \subset F$ for some null measurable set $F$.

Here is a suggestion:

Without loss of generality, if $E \cup Z \in \overline{M}$, while $Z \subset F \in Null(M)$, one can assume that $E \cap F = \phi$. Indeed, otherwise one could write $E \cup Z = (E \setminus F) \cup [(F \cap E) \cup Z]$, and have $E \setminus F \in M, (F \cap E) \cup Z \subset F \in Null(M)$

So, $E^c = E^c \setminus F \cup F \in \overline{M}$, since $E^c \setminus F \in M, F \in Null(M)$